# How to prevent sensitive CLI arguments being logged in journalctl while using sudo?

Tags: command-line, security, sudo, logs

In Ubuntu 16.04, journal logs every sudo command and some includes sensitive arguments (e.g., clear-text password) which I don't want to leave in the log. I have some idea of how to prevent that, but I would like to know if any formal way of doing it, which ideally should be simple and general enough.

For example, a command like below.

```
$ sudo set_account.sh --password SbdLb9W --pin-number 1234 --other-options
```

The journal log may render like this.

```
sudo set_account.sh --password ... --pin-number ... --other-options
```

Thanks.

Thanks everyone for very useful answers and comments. I think I would proceed with the approach of environment variable plus wrapper script.

Comment: Can `set_account.sh` instead `read` the password from the tty? Otherwise it will appear in the process list, which most anyone can view.

Comment: To add onto what @thrig said, try using a text editor on an intermediate file (i.e. vim file.txt), type the password onto that, and invoke the command as `sudo set_account.sh --password $(head -n1 file.txt) --pin-number $(head -n1 file2.txt)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't put passwords in command options.

The correct way would be to use environment variables, like

```
$ MY_PASSWORD=s3cr3t ./mycommand
```

However, `mycommand` would need to know to look in the environment for the password

The password would appear in YOUR shell history, but would not be visible to other users: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/138071/are-environment-variables-entered-directly-before-a-command-visible-to-other-

If you don't want it in your shell history, put the above command in a script and run that script

If `mycommand` calls other processes, be careful not to pass `MY_PASSWORD` to the child processes

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
$ rm -f /home/somewhere/new_account_john
$ touch /home/somewhere/new_account_john
$ chmod 600 /home/somewhere/new_account_john
$ echo "--password SbdLb9W --pin-number 1234" > /home/somewhere/new_account_john
$ sudo set_account.sh --read-options-from /home/somewhere/new_account_john --other-options
$ rm -f /home/somewhere/new_account_john
```

This does still carry the security risk that someone can read the process list with `ps` and see the `echo` command.  A second risk would be a race, i.e. someone writes to the file before you do, or changes it just before the `sudo` (or else, reads from it).

It would, however, solve the immediate request you had.

If you cannot change the `set_account.sh` command then you could try something like

```
$ sudo sh -c 'set_account.sh `cat /home/somewhere/new_account_john` --other-options'
```

instead of the other `sudo` command above, and try whether the cat is called after sudo (it should, but this depends on the quoting syntax of your shell).  The other commands stay the same.